# angular-wizard: Can't use "external scripts" like jQuery UI for example, it does not work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, wizard

So i'm using this module:
github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard 
to make a step-by-step form on my application, everything was working fine till i tried to use a datepicker.
Imitially i tried to use angular-bootstrap datepicker, but it wasn't working, i thought it was a bootstrap problem so i installed Jquery-ui.

Then i realized the problem was with angular-wizard. Every external script that i try to use after this:

```
  <wizard on-finish="finished()" template="templates/wizard-custom.html">
```

doesn't work! (This line instantiate the wizard)

So if i put this code before the line mentioned:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("teste");

        $( "#datepicker" ).click(function(){
                alert("que bosta");
            });

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


        </script>

          <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Everything works fine!
If i put it inside:

```
 <wizard on-finish="finished()" template="templates/wizard-custom.html">

        <script type="text/javascript">
              console.log("teste");

              $( "#datepicker" ).click(function(){
                      alert("que bosta");
                  });

              $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


        </script>

          <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

        (...... other lines that are not relevant....)
     </wizard>
```

Nothing happens!!

I don't understand much profoundly how javascript and angular works, so i have no idea why this is happening. anyone?

I've tried importing the jquery-ui inside the  tag, but it didn't work, i also tried importing jquery-ui on the template "wizard-custom.html" it also didn't work. i'm lost

If you need any other kind of info let me know

### RESOLUTION

I still don't understand exactly what was going on but i've installed this module:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

And now the date picker is working fine!

Accordiing to this page
This is what was going on with using the jquery ui code: http://www.grobmeier.de/angular-js-binding-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-example-07092012.html

> that code will not access the scope of your controller and thus not change the values of your model. You would need to wrap the jQuery UI Datepicker into an Angular.js directive to make this work.

Comment: jQuery plugins need to be initialized in a directive so that element exists when code is run

Comment: @charlietfl i don't understand how i should do that and why this would work, i'm new at angular

Comment: @charlietfl oh also, angular-bootstrap wasn't working iinside of the wizard tag, and it uses a directive called datepicker, i will put the code on the question

Comment: Easy google searc for `angular jquery plugin directive`

Comment: @charlietfl ok, i've found a module! thanks